# Elastic search Unorderered Partial phrase matching with ngram

Tags: elasticsearch

Maybe I am going down the wrong route, but I am trying to set up Elasticsearch to use Partial Phrase matching to return parts of words from any order of a sentence.
Eg. I have the following input

- test name
- tester name
- name test
- namey mcname face
- test

And I hope to do a search for "test name" (or "name test"), and I hope all of these return (hopefully sorted in order of score). I can do partial searches, and also can do out of order searches, but not able to combine the 2. I am sure this would be a very common issue.

Below is my Settings

```
{
"myIndex": {
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "mynGram": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "2",
                        "max_gram": "5"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "custom_analyser": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "mynGram"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "my_tokenizer": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "2",
                        "max_gram": "5"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

My mapping

```
{
"myIndex": {
    "mappings": {
        "myIndex": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "custom_analyser"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And my query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match_phrase": {
                "name": {
                    "query": "test name",
                    "slop": 5
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

not sure if you found your solution - I bet you did because this is such an old post, but I was on the hunt for the same thing and found this: [Query-Time Search-as-you-type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html)

Look up slop.